# Django custom form not loading in modelformset_factory on html template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use my custom form in modelformset_factory but when I set the 'form' attribute in modelformset_factory to my custom form nothing is being displayed. I looked at the documentation and I cannot find what is causing my custom form not to load.

this is view:

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    data = dict()
    ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(Images,form=ImageForm,extra=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():    
            post = form.save(False)
            post.author = request.user
            #post.likes = None
            post.save()
            for f in formset:
                try:
                    i = Images(posts=post, image=f.cleaned_data['image'])
                    i.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            posts = Post.objects.all()
            posts = Post.objects.order_by('-last_edited')
            data['posts'] = render_to_string('home/posts/home_post.html',{'posts':posts},request=request)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = PostForm  
        formset = ImageFormset(queryset=Images.objects.none())     
    context = {
    'form':form,
    'formset':formset,
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('home/posts/post_create.html',context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

this is my custom form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(
        label='',
        widget = forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'style':'display: none;',
                'class':'form-control',
                'required': False})) 
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image', )
```

And this is what im using to load the formset:

```
{{ formset }}
```

Appreciate all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself the issue was I was using display: none in my form!
i simply removed that now my form is:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(
        label='',
        widget = forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'required': False})) 
    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image', )
```